# Google Analytics: hits stop getting counted

Tags: google-analytics

We're implementing Google Analytics in retail consumer kiosk software. There is no Javascript or SDKs or web pages involved - we craft a URL per Measurement Protocol and post it. We find that sometimes hits seem to just stop getting counted. If we watch the Real-Time section on the GA web site we can see that our hits continue to get posted, but over in the Behavior / Screens section the number of screen views for this device for today stops incrementing.

It's not just a "sometimes you have to wait 24 hours" thing, because Tuesday and Wednesday of last week still show zero today. If it's a rate limit, I can't see what - we're nowhere near 200k hits per day (per user, but from our point of view each kiosk is a user - we don't have any means to identify individual users); we shouldn't be hitting 500 hits per session because we send a session start (ec=Session&sc=Start) each time the user does something on the main menu and a session end (ec=Session&sc=End) each time the workflow finishes, which shouldn't ever be more than 20 screens - the default 'idle timeout' definition of a session wouldn't work well for us since a user can legitimately be working on a single screen for 10 minutes or more editing a picture whereas also a user can finish and leave and the next user in line start using the kiosk within just a few seconds; we shouldn't be sending events 'too fast' because it takes a couple seconds for a human to read the screen and reach out and touch a button.

What we observe is that some days it counts up to 340-360 and stops and some days it stays at 0 permanently. Any idea what's happening and how to fix it?

11/24: Today it went up to 352 and then stopped. This was about one hour of activity. All of this has been done with "Highest precision" selected.

12/1: Still same, counts for about one hour, to 347 screen views today, then stops incrementing.

When I look at Audience/Overview it says "Sessions 1". There should be dozens of sessions, split up by when we send (ec=Session&sc=Start). I think it must not be recognizing that as a session, it **must** be using the session timeout (idle), and staying all within a single session, and therefore limiting to 500 hits (we've got some events to go along with the screen views). And this is just **wrong**. Session should end when we say it does.

12/1: One correction, we actually do send sc=start and sc=end, with the values lower-case, as specified by Google.

Comment: For debugging purposes, try accessing Google Analytics in private browsing mode. Let us know if this makes a difference.

Comment: I opened an incognito window. Same results exactly. This was in Chrome. I also fired up IE and opened InPrivate and saw the same results.

Comment: That should eliminate any interference by browser plugins, etc.

Comment: I understand this is provided free by Google, but even so is there any way to get their attention to look at issues like this? Seems they closed help forums and tell us to ask questions right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker did some experimenting and found that sc=start is ignored on t=event hits. It is recognized on t=pageview hits. I changed my reporting a bit to generate a fake pageview when a session starts, just so I could send the sc=start, and now the counts are accurate.